# how to dispatch touch events or rewrite onTouchEvent when use a scollview in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I create a vertical viewpager like this:

```
/** 
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event. 
 */  
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {  
    float width = getWidth();  
    float height = getHeight();  

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;  
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;  

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);  

    return ev;  
}  


@Override  
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev)); 
    swapXY(ev);
    return intercepted;  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));  
}
```

and in the second fragment create a common viewpager with 4 fragments,and so far everything goes well,no conflicts.
Well, I put scrollviews into 3 of them,and this time  when I try to scroll to the top fragment of my vertical viewpager it doesn't work with my first touch in scrollview(If I touch the other parts of this fragment it won't happen).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <com.nangua.xiaomanjflc.widget.SmartScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_project_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/page_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_small"
            android:visibility="visible" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_line"

                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:textColor="@color/font_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_hint" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </com.nangua.xiaomanjflc.widget.SmartScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

What I want is that when I scroll the scrollview over the top, it can be moved softly like my vertical viewpager does.Once I rewrited the onTouchEvent of my vertical viewpager,common viewpager and scrollview found that vertical MotionEvent action was catched by common viewpager and gone so that  vertical viewpager catched nothing.
Now here's my bad solution that I put a callback in the scrollview when it scrolled to top ,the outside handle will noticed my vertical viewpager,and it scroll to the top fragment with calling setCurrentItem(0) method.But actually it seems so weird.
So what should I do when rewriting the onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent or some other useful methods of the conflicted 3 parts?

the scrollview's codes:

```
        public SmartScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        private ISmartScrollChangedListener mSmartScrollChangedListener;

        public interface ISmartScrollChangedListener {
            void onScrolledToBottom();
            void onScrolledToTop();
        }

        public void setScanScrollChangedListener(
                ISmartScrollChangedListener smartScrollChangedListener) {
            mSmartScrollChangedListener = smartScrollChangedListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX,
                boolean clampedY) {
            super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
            if (scrollY == 0) {
                isScrolledToTop = clampedY;
                isScrolledToBottom = false;
            }
            else {
                isScrolledToTop = false;
                isScrolledToBottom = clampedY;
            }
            notifyScrollChangedListeners();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
            super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
                if (getScrollY() == 0) { 
                    isScrolledToTop = true;
                    isScrolledToBottom = false;
                }
                else if (getScrollY() + getHeight() - getPaddingTop()
                        - getPaddingBottom() == getChildAt(0).getHeight()) {        
                    isScrolledToBottom = true;
                    isScrolledToTop = false;
                }
                else {
                    isScrolledToTop = false;
                    isScrolledToBottom = false;
                }
                notifyScrollChangedListeners();
            }
        }

        private void notifyScrollChangedListeners() {
            if (isScrolledToTop) {
                if (mSmartScrollChangedListener != null) {
                    mSmartScrollChangedListener.onScrolledToTop();
                }
            }
            else if (isScrolledToBottom) {
                if (mSmartScrollChangedListener != null) {
                    mSmartScrollChangedListener.onScrolledToBottom();
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isScrolledToTop() {
            return isScrolledToTop;
        }

        public boolean isScrolledToBottom() {
            return isScrolledToBottom;
        }

        public boolean canScroll() {
            View child = getChildAt(0);
            if (child != null) {
                int childHeight = child.getHeight();
                return getHeight() < childHeight;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: instead of that `swapXY` why not to use `RecyclerView` with vertical `LinearLayoutManager`?

Comment: @Justin Mitchell What I'm trying to achieve is that the vertical MotionEvent can be catched by my vertical viewpager when scrolling over the top in the scrollview

Comment: @pskink the vertical viewpager is one of my old component,and there's only two big fragment in it so that the vertical viewpager may works better than the RecyclerView.I think it can happen like this even I replace the vertical viewpager with RecyclerView.